# Parcelable String Array via Intent

Tags: android, arrays, marshalling, parcelable, gson

I've a custom parcelable (simplified) that contains a string array:

```
public class MyClass implements Parcelable {

    public static final Creator<MyClass> CREATOR = new Creator<MyClass>() {
        public MyClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyClass(in);
        }

        public MyClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyClass[size];
        }
    };

    @SerializedName(“tips”)
    private List<String> Tips;

    public MyClass() {
        Tips = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    protected Category(Parcel in) {
        Tips = in.createStringArrayList();
    }

    public List<String> getTips() {
        return Tips;
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeStringList(Tips);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass this parcelable via Intent to another activity. The process is VERY slow and sometimes I get an OOM exception...I don't understand why, I just want to pass a string array...

Comment: how big is that "string array"?

Comment: I reduced it to 2 elements, each one with a short string (more or less 10 chars).

Comment: what is `TipsAC` ? i see `private List<String> Tips;` but not `TipsAC`, also, follow java name convention

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: it looks ok now, are you sure that OOM is in your code? what is traceback?

Comment: I can't reproduce it, it happened only once, now the UI just freeze for some second, the screen becomes black and then I've the correct result. I don't understand how an array of 2 strings can slow down the whole app.

Comment: add some `Log.d` calls around `createStringArrayList` and `writeStringList` and see the `logcat`

Comment: Putting Log.d("DEBUG", Tips.get(0)); after createStringArrayList throws an exception "println needs a message".

Comment: read `Log` documentation then

Comment: I don't think you problem is in the moment you parse your array... Can you show the code of when you parse your array?

Answer (score 0):

Save your array into database and pass id of that record.